# Strings of malicious code to look for after a WordPress/Prestashop hack

Tags: wordpress, prestashop

It's always a struggle to find which files have been created or compromised after a Wordpress or a Prestashop has been hacked, so I've created a PHP script that scans in every files' source code on the serverand looks for the presence of suspicious strings, which are the following:

- gzinflate
- $_REQUEST[$_GET
- fwrite
- file_get_contents

Can you think of any other strings that are often present in malicious code, and specific to them, that I could look for?

Comment: `file_put_contents`, `move_uploaded_file`